# Question about Probability of $A\cup B\cup C$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have a question, so in my textbook they give us this definition:
[image]

So say we have three events: $A$, $B$, and $C$.

If I wanted to find $P(A \cup B \cup C)$, would I do $P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$?

Because don't we also have to subtract the intersection too?

$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap C) + P(A\cap B\cap C)$

This was a "generalization" our Professor went over. But how do I know when to either only add up the probability of the events vs. adding them up and then subtracting the intersections of two, and then adding the intersections of all 3?

Comment: If no two events overlap you can add. Otherwise in general use inclusion-exclusion (can google that) which is just a generalization of your prof's three-set formula.

Comment: So what if the problem makes no mention about them overlapping? Do we use rule of inclusion-exclusion formula?

Comment: Yes, to be safe use inc-exc.

Answer (score 1):

If the events are mutually exclusive then the probability of A AND B, A AND C, B AND C, A AND B AND C is zero. Remember that intersection represents a logical AND. If the events don't influence each other then the probability of them happeneing together is zero.

In notation this would look like:

$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 0 - 0 - 0 + 0 = P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$